# Paypal Direct Payments Api Arguments

Tags: paypal

I am trying to access the Paypal Direct Payements Api using cURL and I get this response:
TIMESTAMP=2020%2d11%2d25T10%3a53%3a01Z&CORRELATIONID=7877664ffef0b&ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=10004&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid%20Request%20Error%2e&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e

An this is the cURL statement minus the credentials:

curl https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp   --insecure    -d VERSION=56.0   -d SIGNATURE=hidden   -d USER=hidden   -d PWD=hidden   -d METHOD=DoDirectPayment   -d PAYMENTACTION=Sale   -d IPADDRESS=   -d AMT=8.88   -d CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa   -d ACCT=4032032245382681   -d EXPDATE=10/2021   -d CVV2=283   -d FIRSTNAME=John   -d LASTNAME=Doe   -d STREET=MohlalaRd   -d CITY=Nelspruit   -d STATE=Mpumalanga   -d ZIP=1201   -d COUNTRYCODE=ZA

Answer (score 0):

> EXPDATE=10/2021

This is the invalid argument, [format is MMYYYY](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/do-direct-payment-nvp/#dodirectpayment-request-message)

DoDirectPayment requires a live PayPal Payments Pro account for use in live and is an old API, you should not be using it in new integrations.  Also version 56 is an extremely old version of the classic NVP API.  If you were to be integrating something like this with a classic API (which you should not be doing), you would at the very least want to use a reasonably recent version such as 202.

---

See [Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/#step-1-enable-your-business-account-for-advanced-credit-and-debit-card-payments) instead, or use Braintree if you need a gateway.

Comment: Braintree isn't supported in my country.

Comment: I did not want to use it for a website, but I wanted to access it from an application written in python3

Comment: If Braintree is not supported in your country, PayPal Payments Pro certaintly isn't.  Try the black "Debit or Credit Card" button of https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -- if you want to use the server pattern on that page, implement two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: Just saw your second comment of no website, well you'll have to open some type of browser to process payments with PayPal

Comment: That's horrible I wanted users to pay entirely from the application, isn't there a way to do this?

Comment: What you're proposing is quite uncommon really and runs into thorny PCI compliance issues. Popping over to an https hosted site is a far more common to process payments, and you will find that the vast majority of modern applications do this.